# Need help with NFC Tags and cryptography

Tags: hash, signature, non-repudiation

I have some NFC-Tags, which will be added to my devices. These NFC Tags are basically EEPROMs with an unique UUID (7-Byte, readonly, public) and some constant parameters (approx. 7-15 Bytes, read and writeable, also public) in it.

1. Can I use a digital signature in order to tell if a given NFC-Tag belongs to my devices and if the parameters haven't been changed by an evil user?  (Message for signing algorithm would be UUID + Parameters)
2. I'm using an 8-bit microcontroller with very limited resources on the NFC-Reader side for the verification process. Therefore the verification step should be as easy as possible (signing the tags can be done on a powerful PC). Which Algorithm would you use for this application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preliminary caveat**: the un-clonability of your NFC tags is relative. A mobile phone with NFC is all it takes to read one, perhaps surreptitiously. Then a number of devices like [proxmark3](https://github.com/Proxmark/proxmark3) can emulate it. A static digital signature would not prevent that.

> 1. Can I use a digital signature in order to tell if a given NFC-Tag belongs to my devices and if the parameters haven't been changed by an evil user?

**No, a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) can't authenticate the data in that size-constrained tag: more memory is required that the tag allows**.

All digital signatures schemes add at the very least $2b$-bit of data for $b$-bit security, so for 80-bit security (which is NOT safe enough by modern standards) we are talking 20 bytes, more than the question quotes. And that's for some [BLS signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh%E2%80%93Lynn%E2%80%93Shacham) schemes pushing things to the max, which (although [reportedly used](http://sac2013.irmacs.sfu.ca/slides/s1.pdf#page=8) with great success) have not their security strongly vetted. The industry standard is $b=128$-bit security with $4b$-bit signature, thus 64 bytes (e.g. [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519)). I know nothing well-seasoned below $3b$-bit overhead for small signed data, or $2b$-bit for larger data (above about 220 bytes).

---

> 2. I'm using an 8-bit microcontroller with very limited resources on the NFC-Reader side for the verification process. Therefore the verification step should be as easy as possible (signing the tags can be done on a powerful PC). Which Algorithm would you use for this application?

Among common signature schemes, only RSA and [Rabin signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_signature_algorithm) have fast verification (seconds) on 8-bit microcontrollers, but unfortunately their minimal data requirement is like 2048-bit (256 bytes) for modern security. Thus you'd need 256 bytes of memory in the tag for the signature (in addition to the UUID; the rest may come for free, see below).

With RSA/Rabin per ISO/IEC 9796-2 using SHA-256, it is possible to embed payload data into the signature (e.g. up to 222 bytes for 256-byte signature), and this payload becomes available as a byproduct of signature verification, which is fast. That's RSA/Rabin signature with message recovery. It essentially achieves $2b$-bit size overhead for $b$-bit security, for a payload at least a certain size.

All common signature schemes requiring less memory are considerably slower for signature verification, in the order of a minute for 128-bit security given the low-end CPU.

---

Feasible options include (not exclusive, not limitative)

- Using a [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) rather than a digital signature. That solves the size and speed issues (8 bytes and a tenth of second is ample), but unfortunately a verification device contains the secret key that also allows to compute a MAC that makes a tag working. If an adversary can get hold of a verification device, these might need to be tamper-proof, thus slightly more expensive. And it can't be entirely ruled out that a verification device is successfully attacked and its secret key extracted (though that can be made extremely hard, even certified so).
- Going online: the UUID can be used as index in a server, knowing if the tag is registered or not. The server can digitally sign that it vets the tag with that UUID as OK, and it can use a system with lightweight signature verification. That has the advantage of allowing a dynamic black/whitelist.

Comment: Don't forget about replay and antenna extension attacks...

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation and the feasible options. I'll probably go for the Message Authentication Codes...